# Examples of functions summables in $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, statistical-mechanics, gibbs-measure

I know that $f_0(x)={ 1 \over \vert \vert x\vert \vert^\alpha}$, $f_0(0)=1$ , $\alpha>d$, $d\in   \mathbb{N}$ is summable in $\mathbb{Z}^d$, i.e.

$$
\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^d} f(x)<\infty.
$$
I am searching for other examples of  $f(x)>{ 1 \over \vert \vert x\vert \vert^\alpha}$ (except maybe for a finite numbers of 'x's)  that  are summables in $\mathbb{Z}^d$  or $V_n= [1,n]^d \bigcap \mathbb{Z}^d$.

Comment: Like $e^{-||x||}$?

Comment: You could always take your favorite summable sequence $a_n$, and then spread it around $\mathbb{Z}^d$ appropriately.

Comment: I found this $f(x)={ \ln \| x\|  \over  \| x\| ^{\alpha }}$. Can you give me other example?